# Make a websocket connection from iframe with different domain

Tags: javascript, ssl, iframe, websocket

I am not sure if the scenario is possible, and I could not find something that it is not.
I would like to embed multiple iframes in my web application (react). I have a websocket server on localhost or eventually inside my local network.
Is it possible to connect to the websocket server from inside the iframes? All iframes have a different domain and also different from the page in which they are hosted.
The connection should be secure.

[image]

Comment: One cannot directly access `localhost` on a different computer from outside. `localhost` is just always the local computer, i.e. the computer running the browser in your example. The common way to expose internal services like a websocket server to the outside is to either make them not listen on localhost only or (more common) put a public accessible reverse proxy in front of these.

Comment: So, is there no way to communicate over the local network between the iframe and the websocket server without going over the internet?

Comment: A site can be made available on the local network too, the same way I described. But again, `localhost` is always the local computer so accessing a remote computer (even on the LAN) as `localhost` is not possible.

Comment: Would it be something like proxiing the requests from '//localhost:12345' to '//abc.com' and back? But will the localhost wss access than work ?

Comment: You can use tools/services like ngrok(https://ngrok.com/) to expose your localhost